# Remove contiguous elements in array in a more functional way

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I try to remove elements in an array if the number of contiguous element is greater than two.

Here are the tests:

```
test('delete pieces if number of piece contiguous greater than two', t => {
    t.deepEqual([null, null, null], removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 1]));
    t.deepEqual([null, null, null, null], removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 1, 1]));
    t.deepEqual([null, null, null, null, 4], removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 1, 1, 4]));
    t.deepEqual([4, null, null, null, null], removeIdenticalPieces([4, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
    t.deepEqual([1, 1, 4, 1, 1], removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 4, 1, 1]));
    t.deepEqual([1, 1], removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1]));
});
```

Here is a working function:

```
function removeIdenticalPieces(line) {
    const newLine = [];
    while (line.length !== 0) {
        const firstPiece = line.shift();
        let nbContiguousPieces = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
            let currentPiece = line[i];
            if (firstPiece !== currentPiece) {
                break;
            }
            nbContiguousPieces += 1
        }
        if (nbContiguousPieces >= 2) {
            newLine.push(null);
            for (let j = 0; j < nbContiguousPieces; j++) {
                line.shift();
                newLine.push(null)
            }
        } else {
            newLine.push(firstPiece);
            for (let k = 0; k < nbContiguousPieces; k++) {
                newLine.push(line.shift())
            }
        }
    }
    return newLine;
}
```

Does a more "functional" way exist to do the same?

**Edit:** thank you for your solutions.

Here the jsperf https://jsperf.com/removeidenticalpieces3.

I take the solution of @lilobase because it is faster and more **readable**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close to Damien's solution. If we hardcode the lookups, we can achieve a simpler version :

```
const lookAfter = (i, a) => (a[i] == a[i+1] == a[i+2]);
const lookBehind = (i, a) => (a[i] == a[i-1] == a[i-2]);
const lookAround = (i, a) => (a[i] == a[i-1] == a[i+1]);
const deleteContiguousItems = array => array.map((item, i) => (lookAfter(i, array) || lookAround(i, array) || lookBehind(i, array)) ? null : item);
```

And if you inline all the declarations you'll get the simplest expressions (not the most readable)

```
const lookAndReturn = (val, i, a) => (val == a[i+1] == a[i+2]) || (val == a[i-1] == a[i-2]) || (val == a[i-1] == a[i+1]) ? null : val;
const removeIdenticalPieces = array => array.map(lookAndReturn);
```

Answer (score 4):

One neat thing about `array.reduce` is that the carry doesn't need to be your resulting value. You can actually hold a record of previous runs on it by carrying an object.

I would think something along the lines of:

```
line.reduce((carry, current, index) => {
  // If current is same a previous, increase repeats
  // If repeats === 3, splice the last 3  in result and replace with null,
  // Else, add current to the result
  // update previous and repeats a
  // return updated carry
}, {
  result: [],
  previous: null,
  repeats: 0
}).result;
```

Answer (score 3):

My first instinct was to use map, and then deconstruct each operation in a separate function:

```
const isContiguous = ({ line, key1, key2, value}) => (
  line[key1] && line[key1] === value
  && line[key2] && line[key2] === value
)

const isTwiceContiguous = ({ line, key, value }) => (
  isContiguous({ line, key1: key - 2, key2: key - 1, value})
  || isContiguous({ line, key1: key - 1, key2: key + 1, value})
  || isContiguous({ line, key1: key + 1, key2: key + 2, value})
)

const removeIdenticalPieces = (line) => (
  line.map((value, key) => isTwiceContiguous({ line, key, value }) ? null : value)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this problem:

```
const last = (a) => a ? a[a.length - 1] : null
const init = (a) => a ? a.slice(0, -1) : null
const flatten = (a) => 
  a.reduce((m, v) => m.concat(Array.isArray(v) ? flatten(v) : v), [])

const splitReducer = (m, v) => 
  last(last(m)) === v 
    ? init(m).concat([last(m).concat(v)])
    : m.concat([[v]])

const splitWhenValueDiffer = (list) => 
  list.reduce(splitReducer, [])

const removeIdenticalPieces = (list) =>
  flatten(splitWhenValueDiffer(list).map(a => a.length > 2 ? a.map(v => null) : a))

console.log(removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 1])) // [null, null, null]
console.log(removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 1, 1])) // [null, null, null, null]
console.log(removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 1, 1, 4])) // [null, null, null, null, 4]
console.log(removeIdenticalPieces([4, 1, 1, 1, 1])) // [4, null, null, null, null]
console.log(removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1, 4, 1, 1])) // [1, 1, 4, 1, 1]
console.log(removeIdenticalPieces([1, 1])) // [1, 1]
```

The first three functions are just your classical functional utilities.

Then the `splitWhenValueDiffer` and its `splitReducer` takes an array and will split it whenever a value is different than the previous one. For example, given `[1,1,2,2,3]` it returns `[[1,1],[2,2],[3]]`.

Finally the `removeIdenticalPieces` function splits the passed-in list using `splitWhenValueDiffer` then map the array and replaces every array of a size greater than 2 with an array of same length containing `null` and flatten everything.

As you can notice, every function is pure, has no local variables and never mutate anything.